# Upload an image from Wordpress to Flickr

Tags: wordpress, flickr

Does anyone know a Wordpress plugin which uploads automatically a picture from Wordpress to Flickr? The are tons of plugins to pull pictures from Flickr to Wordpress but what I would like to do is add an image trough the Wordpress back end and automatically add ti to a specific Flickr account.

Thank you,
Maria.

Answer (score 1):

While I've not tried it myself, I believe [WordPress Flickr Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-flickr-manager/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This plugin is no longer avilable